# How can I increase memory access speed in a GPU? (CUDA)

Tags: optimization, memory, cuda, gpu

First I need to describe the application for which I am using CUDA.

It is a fairly standard heat flow simulation. I take a bunch of 3D arrays of floats (mutable temperature and heat, and constant k value, sar_value, and a few others) and copy them into linear arrays allocated on the GPU. All of these are in global memory.

Next, I launch a kernel function that computes heat flow. I launch this kernel with a 2 dimensional block construct and a 1D thread construct. The block corresponds to x and y coordinates of the simulation cube that we are performing heat flow calculations on. The thread corresponds the the z coordinate. All thread/block coordinates are multiples of the total cube size, as to maximize performance.

Next, on each cell I perform a lengthy calculation. All of the arrays are linear, so I have prepped offsets to compute the next cell in the z, y and x directions. The bulk of spatial locality occurs in write/read memory, so texture memory is not an option there. In total, per calculation there are 2 writes to large arrays, 6 constant large array reads (as in one index of a 300 MB array of floats), 8 mutable large array reads, 6 constant small array reads (as in cube root of 300 MB). All of this occurs in two lines of code. I didn't include multiple reads of the same memory location as separate reads, as I am assuming that they are cached.

Second I will describe the results I have been having with this calculation.

I get about 225 million cells/second on a Tesla C1060. On large data sets (40-60 million cells), I see no difference in performance between launching 1 thread per cell vs 1 thread per 2 cells vs 1 thread per 4 cells, all the way up to a certain point. This indicates to me that the limiting factor with the calculation is the actual memory fetching. When I launch 1 thread for multiple blocks, I relieve the memory overload on the system and so each calculation is faster, although the calculations are less parallel - netting to no performance gain, + or - a percent or two.

What have I tried? I have tried putting my most spatially local constant large array into 3D texture memory - disastrous 3-4x slowdown. I have deemed constant memory to be not viable because the data access pattern is such that each index in the large array is only accessed once or twice, and besides, I do not necessarily know the size of the input at compile time. I have tried 1D textures on the large constant arrays; also bad.

Is there anything more I can do? Also, if you can see the number of bytes fetches per second (225 million/sec * 100 or so bytes), it is well within, by roughly a multiple of 10, the memory bandwidth of a Tesla C1060. Why is the memory the limiting factor? I saw somewhere that someone "tiled" their data set for a similar heat flow calculation (I think in a paper by the people behind "Mint"), what does this mean?

Thank you for any answers. Please feel free to ask any questions in the comments section.

Comment: Thank you for stating your question so clearly. Have you run your program in a CUDA profiler? The Compute Visual Profiler will analyze your program and generate a set of recommendations. What are the recommendations? Is each thread for a different cell? Have you attempted to determine what kind of memory access patterns are generated by a warp?

Comment: Have you read [this paper](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/CUDA_Zone/papers/gpu_3dfd_rev.pdf) on 3D high order finite difference schemes in CUDA, and looked at [these slides](http://mc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/images/0/0a/M02_4.pdf) (from p 25)?

Comment: Roger, I haven't run it through a CUDA profiler yet, but I will do that - thanks for the suggestion. No thread writes to the same cell in the same time step (I think that is what you were asking?). There are coincidental reads of the place in the array by different threads if they are next to each other in the cube. The memory access pattern from each warp is something I haven't paid attention to. I will now after I have heard it mentioned in these answers. Thanks.

Comment: talonmies, thanks for the links! I haven't seen those yet. Is there an easy way to find helpful, more scholarly papers like that? I have just had time to glance at them right now, but those will definitely be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Next, on each cell I perform a lengthy calculation. All of the arrays are linear, so I have prepped offsets to compute the next cell in the z, y and x directions.

Carefully consider what type of access pattern you are getting in the arrays, within a warp. The threads in a warp should access consecutive addresses in a "row-major" order. If you by chance ended up with something like a "column-major" access pattern, your code will be issuing many more memory transactions than necessary.

Section 2.2, Thread Hierarchy, in the CUDA Programming Guide 4.2 describes how the thread indexes map to thread IDs. Check to see that consecutive thread IDs also lead to (at least largely) consecutive array indexes.